# Using the Microsoft Graph how do I look up a group by email address?

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the [Graph Explorer](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer) to play with the [Microsoft Graph](http://graph.microsoft.io/).  I understand you can access a group by specifying its id, like so -

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/14481298-e121-4d97-91d5-3fe555aa2871
```

and you can get its members as well like this -

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/14481298-e121-4d97-91d5-3fe555aa2871/members
```

But it isn't clear to me how you lookup a group by its email address and list the members in one call.  I now know, so I thought I would share, and also ask if there is a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the group by email you can filter by the mail property.  However this does return an array, which is slightly different from the original query.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/?$filter=mail+eq+'sampleDL@example.com'
```

To get the members you can expand members.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/?$filter=mail+eq+'sampleDL@example.com'&$expand=members
```

Comment: how can I filter this  using $select=id,mail   ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.