# Using the Microsoft Graph to expand a DL, can $select be used after an $expand to reduce response size?

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to find all the members of a distribution list, given it's email address.  Supposing I have `sampleDL@example.com` and want to expand its members, returning only `displayName` and `userPrincipalName`, can I do that?

I'm using the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer), logged in as myself.  In the query box, I can get the [group and members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221122/using-the-microsoft-graph-how-do-i-look-up-a-group-by-email-address/37221123#37221123) with $filter and $expand -

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/?$filter=mail+eq+'sampleDL@example.com'&$expand=members
```

But the response is huge, having expanded each member to its full property set. I'd like to only include `displayName` and `userPrincipalName`.  I thought might be able to slim down the response with `$select` -

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/?$filter=mail+eq+'sampleDL@example.com'&$expand=members($select=displayName,userPrincipalName)
```

But doing so returns an error -

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "Term 'members($select=displayName,userPrincipalName)' is not valid in a $select or $expand expression.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "02f3471c-9e93-4bcc-8b7f-dffd187cd33a",
            "date": "2016-05-13T23:04:00"
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible?  Am I on the right track?  Is the select statement wrong, because the returned output is an array?

Comment: Had you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this possible? Am I on the right track? Is the select statement wrong, because the returned output is an array?

Theoretically, it could be done with:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/?$filter=mail+eq+'email@domain.onmicrosoft.com'&$expand=members$select=members/displayName
```

But as I tested, the Group API does not support the "multiple navigation properties".

BTW, the type of members property in group object is directory object collection, which means the item in members could be any type of objects inherit from directory object (for example, user or group), but the "displayName" and "userPrincipalName" are defined in micrsoft.graph.user object.

Comment: Good point that not everything would have those properties - an object that is itself another distribution list wouldn't have a UPN.